# Rename Time sheet Period in Project Online

Tags: project-online

It came to my notice that the last week's period label is incorrect. I should be able to change it now. Will it have any impact on Time-sheets already submitted if associated Period label is renamed?

Answer (score 0):

Why not make a copy of the app and test it?  Go to [List Settings > Save as Template](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-list-templates-c3884ad1-bc49-44b8-b3d6-3bc6a01eb393).  Then create a new app and name it `Project Online Test`.  Change the setting and see what happens.

Comment: I am sorry, which list? I am talking about timesheet reporting periods and impact of renaming their label.